# CS:Go on Ubuntu renders Incorrectly

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it's working fine, but CS:GO don't.
When I open up the game the menu is fine, but when I start the match, some walls and models will be corrupted and messy.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me? The wireframe is on purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a hardware or driver problem.

Try reinstalling your drivers, if that doesn't fix it, roll back to another version.

If this doesn't work, try the game on another platform (like Windows), if it still has this issue, it probably means that your hardware (most likely GPU) has some issues.

Comment: I was using the X.Org driver instead of Nvidia